# Android Application is not installed

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried signing the application and tried just debugging it.  I have the Galaxy nexus.  i have been able to run on the device before but now when I compile and build it shows up on the device but when i try and run it it tells me the application is not installed.  I have tried to reinstall it too!

thanks

Comment: Have you checked logcat to see if there's an error of some sort?

Comment: try reconnect the phone, restart eclipse or project -> clean. Or you can try go to <path to android-sdk>/platform-tools and run ./adb uninstall project-package and run ./adb install project-package again.  Just a shot in the field but hope something of that helps.

Comment: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.michaelamici.cloudcopy/.CloudCopyActivity } from ProcessRecord{41c93df0 448:com.android.launcher/10029} (pid=448, uid=10029) requires android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: You need to add Internet permission for the app you're installing, in its manifest file, by adding the following line to the manifest file:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
Do this before the <application ...> tag

Comment: @Luis Miguel Serrano, please post as answer so OP can accept.

Comment: ok Kgrover, I just posted it as an answer now, so that @Michael Amici can please accept.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Internet permission for the app you're installing, in its manifest file, by adding the following line to the manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Do this before the `<application ...>` tag